# output both stderr and stdout on console and store them in a file at same time

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

may I output both `stdout` and `stderr` on console screen and store one of them into a log file?

I write a test shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo OUT! >&1
echo ERR! >&2
```

I can output both of them on screen just by run the script:

```
$./test 
OUT!
ERR!
```

I can output `stderr` and catch `stdout` into log file by:

```
$./test | tee 1>log
ERR!

$cat log 
OUT!
```

I can output nothing but catch all `stdout` and `stderro` into log file by:

```
$./test 2>&1| tee 1>log

$cat log 
OUT!
ERR!
```

I can output both of `stdout` and `stderr` and catch all of them into a log file by:

```
$./test 2>&1 | tee log
OUT!
ERR!

$cat log 
OUT!
ERR!
```

I can output both can catch `stdout` into log file by:

```
$./test | tee 2>&1 log
ERR!
OUT!

$cat log 
OUT!
```

My questions are:

1. how to just output `stdout` and catch `stderr` into file?(I tried `./test|tee 2>log`, but doesn't work)
2. how to just output both and catch `stderr` into file?

Comment: Related/Cross-duplicate (on Stack Overflow) : http://stackoverflow.com/a/692407/2228310

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 1. how to just output stdout and catch stderr into file?(I tried
>      ./test|tee 2>log, but doesn't work)

```
$ ./test 2>log
OUT!
$ cat log
ERR!
```

> 2. how to just output both and catch stderr into file?

```
$ ./test 2>&1 >/dev/tty | tee log
OUT!
ERR!
$ cat log
ERR!
```

If this expression was to be part of a larger pipeline, then you may want to avoid the use of `/dev/tty`.  One way to do that is to swap stdout and stderr.  To do this swap, we need to create a third file handle like so:

```
$ exec 3>&1; ./test 2>&1 1>&3 | tee log; exec 3>&-
OUT!
ERR!
$ cat log
ERR!
```

The first statement, `exec 3>&1`, assigns file handle 3 to the current stdout (whatever that might be).  Then, `./test 2>&1 1>&3 | tee log` pipes stderr to the `tee` command while sending stdout to file handle 3.  Finally, for good housekeeping, `exec 3>&-` closes file handle 3.

#### Additional notes and comments

Regarding:

> I can output stderr and catch stdout into log file by:
>
> ```
> $./test | tee 1>log
> ERR!
> $cat log 
> OUT!
> ```

That can be simplified to:

```
$ ./test >log
ERR!
$ cat log
OUT!
```

Also, regarding:

> I can output nothing but catch all stdout and stderro into log file
>   by:
>
> ```
> $ ./test 2>&1| tee 1>log
> $ cat log 
> OUT!
> ERR!
> ```

That can be simplified to:

```
$ ./test >log 2>&1
$ cat log
OUT!
ERR!
```

Or, with `bash`, but not POSIX shell, a still simpler form is possible:

```
$ ./test &>log
$ cat log
OUT!
ERR!
```

Answer (score 7):

Shells redirections should be fairly enough. First, to redirect `stderr` to a file...

```
$ ./test 2> myfile.txt
```

Here, `stdout` remains the screen, since it wasn't redirected. `myfile.txt` will contain ERR.

Then, if you want to output both, and still catch `stderr` into a file, you'll probably have to go in two steps with a little command substitution...

```
$ ./test 2> >(tee myfile.txt >&2)
```

This will send the error stream to the `tee` process, which will reprint them. `stdout` remains untouched. [For more information, have a look at this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/692407/2228310).

Similarly, if you want to catch `stdout` into a file, and leave `stderr` untouched...

```
$ ./test > >(tee myfile.txt)
```

Comment: +1 for not involving tty. It is more flexible if we want to use it in a pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Okay Guys and Girls...

Just to enrich this thread, I thought it would be better to post an answer with a general simplified case.

**Outputs stdout and stderr to terminal and catch stdout and stderr into file...**

Test if stdout and stderr outputs to terminal and file...

```
rm -f test.log
ping 127.0.0.1 -c 6 2>&1 | tee test.log
cat test.log
```

Confirm if stderr outputs to terminal and file...

```
rm -f test.log
ping e.r.r.or -c 6 2>&1 | tee test.log
cat test.log
```

**Thanks! =D**

[**Ref.:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/12928057/3223785 ]